# Artisan migrate doesn't work in prod when a migration file name is in the future

Tags: laravel, database-migration

Many packages produce migration files that are dated today.  Other packages come with migrations that were created a while ago.  This can screw with key restrictions and dependancies.

So, in my packages I will sometimes date the migration file names a few thousand years into the future.  (I know... fabulous solution.)  The only hiccup I have with this ~ is that a setting of .env APP_ENV=production will prevent my future dated migrations from running.

I'm open to suggestions and better work-arounds.

Comment: What type of key restrictions and dependencies are you referring to?

Comment: @Devon An example would be a mandatory foreign key from a table created in package A to/from a table created in package B.